# MongoSinkConnector expect to find a schema subject that doesn't exist

Tags: mongodb, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-schema-registry, mongodb-kafka-connector

I'm trying to use the connect MongoDB kafka connector sink (mongodb-kafka-connect-mongodb-1.7.0) to write avro event from kafka to MongoDB.

I have a schema registry set up that works with the kafka consumer example or my custom one, they are I both able to deserialize the event and print them.

On the other hand when  I run the connector I get the following exception:

```
Subject '<my-avro-schema-name>-value' not found.; error code: 40401
```

The higher level stack trace message are :

- > Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Error retrieving Avro value schema version for id 11
- > Caused by: org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.DataException: Failed to deserialize data for topic client-order-request to Avro:

And indeed this subject or this id doesn't exist in the schema-registry, actually the highest id I have is 10 and I do have a subject named `<my-avro-schema-name>-key`.

Why is the MongoSinkConnector trying find a subject that doesn't exist ?

Connect properties:

```
bootstrap.servers=<value>
offset.storage.file.filename=/tmp/connect.offsets
offset.flush.interval.ms=10000
plugin.path=/git/1.libraries/kafka_2.12-2.2.0/plugins
```

MongoSink properties:

```
name=<my-avro-schema-name>-sink
connector.class=com.mongodb.kafka.connect.MongoSinkConnector
connection.uri=mongodb://<value>
database=Test
collection=test
topics=test
key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter

value.converter=io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter
value.converter.schema.registry.url=http://<address>
```

schema-registry.properties:

```
listeners=http://0.0.0.0:8081
kafkastore.bootstrap.servers=<address>
kafkastore.topic=_schemas
debug=false
auto.register.schemas=false
use.latest.version=true
```

Kafka producer configuraton:

```
Properties props = new Properties();
props.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "<broker-address>");
props.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);
props.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, KafkaAvroSerializer.class);
props.put(ProducerConfig.CLIENT_ID_CONFIG, "Kafka Avro  Producer");
props.put("schema.registry.url", "<schema-registry>");

KafkaProducer<String, AllEventsUnion> producerRequest = new KafkaProducer<>(props);

AllEventsUnion clientOrderRequest = createClientOrderRequest();
            
final ProducerRecord<String, AllEventsUnion> producerOrderRequest = new ProducerRecord<>("all-events-union",
                    "ClientOrderRequest-" + calendar.getTimeInMillis(), clientOrderRequest);
```

The AllEventsUnion is a union avro schema of multiple types. I'm using it to send different event type to the same kafka topic, which is why I thought I needed to register it before hand. But apparently you don't need to register schema before using them  in the schema registry ?

Answer (score 1):

> I do have a subject named `<my-avro-schema-name>-key`

This would indicate you have Avro keys.

Then why use `key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter` rather than AvroConverter?

> indeed this subject or this id doesn't exist in the schema-registry

Then your Avro producer, upstream from the connector (if exists), is having a problem and has not registered the schema/subject or actually written Avro data using the schema registry.

> Why is the MongoSinkConnector trying find a subject that doesn't exist ?

Because you've set this, and the data in the topic contains the ID to some non-existing subject.

```
value.converter=io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter
```

Registering a schema after the data is produced will not modify data that's already in the topic you're consuming with other Avro information

Comment: tbh I don't even know where the subject <my-avro-schema-name>-key come from.Basically it appears when i write the first avro message, so it does mean it used the schema registry right ?

Comment: I will edit my original message but basically I have all the schema that I want to ingest regirstered already in the schema registry. Those correspond to the object I'm sending to the kafka topic. I'm using the value.converter in order to convert the actual avro event that is stored in the kafka topic and should be consumed by the mongoDB sink, but you're telling me it won't use the schema I already registered for it ?

Comment: Subject registration happens automatically from the upstream producer if configured with the Avro serializers. It appears that only the key serializer was set to use Avro, and the value was not. I'm only guessing since you've not shown the producer code, but the consumer (sink) must match the serialization formats of the producer, and schema registration doesn't automatically convert anything

Comment: I think my case is a bit hard to explain but I thought I had to register the schema in the first place since I'm using a union avro schema to have multiple event type in the same topic. I edited my message with the producer configuration. and conf.

Comment: Yes, schemas need registered, but the producer serializer will do that automatically, by default. Consumers shouldn't be registering anything because they assume data is already available. With your shown code, the value subject should get created since it's using Avro serializer, and not the key one since it's using string serializer

Comment: I noticed I also have a AllEventsUnion-value present but not an AllEventsUnion-key.
I think I understand why, so basically I have this AllEventsUnion that carries with it all the event type. When I'm sending an event I put the child event type as a AllEventsUnion, that would explain why only the AllEventsUnion-value is generated. Then I pipe this event to a client-order-request topic which is why a client-order-request-key is generated but the value is still AllEventsUnion so it doesn't create the client-order-request-value. Does it make any sens.

Comment: Yes, that makes sense, but only if you overwrote the subject naming strategy to use the record name rather than the topic name (which you haven't according to the shown code)

Comment: Where might have I done such things ? You have the schema registry parameter in my post such as auto.register.schemas=false
use.latest.version=true

Comment: Docs: https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/schema-registry/serdes-develop/index.html#subject-name-strategy

Comment: I knew this one but I have the default parameter. Actually I managed to write the event to mongo db by sending the ClientOrderRequestEvent and not the AllEventUnion events. It seems that the mongoDB connector cannot write avro unions.

Comment: Just found out that it's stated it's the connector doesn't support union type with more than 2 elements.

https://www.mongodb.com/docs/kafka-connector/current/introduction/data-formats/#avro-schema